# Do any modules (other than the GPU module) actually require a GPU?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I need to use OpenCV on a low powered Windows device. I want to do facial recognition but my machine does not have a GPU.

I am curious which modules will work without a GPU. Do all of them work except for the GPU module? Does facial recognition have a dependency on GPU? Do any of the other libraries have a dependency on the GPU module?

Comment: No, they don't require GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate module for gpu named as "gpu". All other modules works without gpu as per my experience.  You want to look this for face recognition  in opencv. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html